# Easy-to-use program to add electronic signatures to PDFs?

Tags: pdf, image-editor, signature

My mother needs to add electronic signatures to documents, preferably en-masse (if this feature is at all possible). Because I am a busy person, I want it to be easy enough to use that she doesn't have to constantly ask me for help. Adobe Acrobat Reader, from experience, doesn't fall under that umbrella. If the program manipulates PDFs, that is good; if it manipulates .pages files, that's even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention .pages files, I'm assuming your mother runs macOS. Apple's Preview has long had a nifty feature to create, manage, and add signatures to PDF files. [Here's how it works.](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/fill-out-and-sign-pdf-forms-prvw35725/mac)

I'm not sure what "en-masse" entails for you, but you can—pretty easily—add signatures to a bunch of documents by:

- opening all documents in Preview;
- inserting a signature (as per instructions above);
- copying said signature, and
- pasting it into every other open document.

Answer (score 0):

My company offers many digital signing products and libraries.  One solution is Signer.Digital Desktop or Signer.Digital Server which fulfills your requirement of auto signing pdf documents in bulk.

India's no. 1 private bank is using Signer.Digital server software to sign 2L pdf documents per hour!

Free pdf signing is also available at https://web.signer.digital which requires a browser extension that is also completely free!